# Dynamic Pivot Table, Rows not Condensing Correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using a Dynamic Pivot Table, I'm trying to display rows for each Year and Month (`YM`), their Zip code, Region, the count of New Callers, the count of Repeat Callers, and a count of what type of Callers these are.

In a scenario where I have the same YM, Zip, Region but both New and Repeat Callers I expect to see a row for both New and Repeat so I can differentiate between the Caller Type counts.

**Here is my SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56bc6/1

I have setup the data prior to being pivoted as `[InitialData]` and the expected results as `[ExpectedResults]`

The third result set shown in that link is where I'm at now.

---

Here I have hidden the Create and Insert SQL scripts

```js
CREATE TABLE InitialData
 (
    [YM] int -- YYYYMM date format
   ,[Zip] varchar(5)
   ,[Region] varchar(18)
   ,[NewCallers] int
   ,[RepeatCallers] int
   ,[CallerType] varchar(27)
   ,[CallerTypeCount] int
 )
;
 
INSERT INTO InitialData
 ([YM], [Zip], [Region], [NewCallers], [RepeatCallers], [CallerType], [CallerTypeCount])
VALUES
 (201805, NULL, NULL, 3, 0, 'Family / Friend', 3),
 (201805, NULL, NULL, 2, 0, 'Other', 2),
 (201805, NULL, NULL, 86, 0, 'Parent', 86),
 (201805, NULL, NULL, 6, 0, 'Professional', 6),
 (201805, '03598', NULL, 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201805, '56401', NULL, 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201805, '72209', NULL, 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201805, '85007', 'Phoenix South', 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201805, '85008', 'Phoenix South', 0, 3, 'Other', 3),
 (201805, '85008', 'Phoenix South', 2, 0, 'Family / Friend', 2),
 (201805, '85008', 'Phoenix South', 4, 0, 'Parent', 4),
 (201805, '85008', 'Phoenix South', 2, 0, 'Professional', 2),
 (201805, '85008', 'Phoenix South', 1, 0, 'Business', 1),
 (201805, '85009', 'Phoenix South', 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201805, '85013', 'Phoenix North', 2, 0, 'Parent', 2),
 (201805, '85014', 'Phoenix North', 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201805, '85143', 'Pinal', 2, 0, 'Parent', 2),
 (201805, '85201', 'Southeast Maricopa', 0, 4, 'Other', 4),
 (201805, '85203', 'Southeast Maricopa', 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201806, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, 'Other', 1),
 (201806, NULL, NULL, 70, 0, 'Parent', 70),
 (201806, NULL, NULL, 9, 0, 'Professional', 9),
 (201806, '85257', 'East Maricopa', 1, 0, 'Parent', 1),
 (201806, '85258', 'East Maricopa', 0, 2, 'Other', 2),
 (201806, '85258', 'East Maricopa', 2, 0, 'Parent', 2),
 (201806, '85283', 'East Maricopa', 6, 0, 'Parent', 6)
;

CREATE TABLE ExpectedResults
(
   [YM] int
  ,[Zip] varchar(5)
  ,[Region] varchar(18)
  ,[NewCallers] int
  ,[RepeatCallers] int
  ,[Business] int
  ,[Family / Friend] int  
  ,[Other] int
  ,[Parent] int
  ,[Professional] int
);

INSERT INTO ExpectedResults
VALUES
   (201805, null, null, 97, 0, 0, 3, 2, 86, 6)
  ,(201805, 03598, null, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201805, 56401, null, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201805, 72209, null, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201805, 85007, 'Phoenix South', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201805, 85008, 'Phoenix South', 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0)
  ,(201805, 85008, 'Phoenix South', 9, 0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 2)
  ,(201805, 85009, 'Phoenix South', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201805, 85013, 'Phoenix North', 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
  ,(201805, 85014, 'Phoenix North', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201805, 85143, 'Pinal', 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
  ,(201805, 85201, 'Southeast Maricopa', 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0)
  ,(201805, 85203, 'Southeast Maricopa', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201806, null, null, 80, 0, 0, 1, 0, 70, 9)
  ,(201806, 85257, 'East Maricopa', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ,(201806, 85258, 'East Maricopa', 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)
  ,(201806, 85258, 'East Maricopa', 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
  ,(201806, 85283, 'East Maricopa', 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0);
  
CREATE TABLE CallerTypes
(
   [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
  ,[Name] VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO CallerTypes
VALUES
   (NEWID(), 'Business')
  ,(NEWID(), 'Family / Friend')
  ,(NEWID(), 'Other')
  ,(NEWID(), 'Parent')
  ,(NEWID(), 'Professional');
```

Here I have hidden my current SQL script to pivot the data

```js
SELECT * FROM [InitialData];
//
SELECT * FROM [ExpectedResults];
//
-- What I have tried so far:
DECLARE
   @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
  ,@sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';

-- Setup column names using dbo.CallerTypes
SELECT
  @columns += N', PivotResults.' + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
 [CallerTypes].[Name]
  FROM CallerTypes
  
  INNER JOIN [InitialData]
 ON [CallerTypes].[Name] = [InitialData].[CallerType]
) AS x;

-- Setup Dynamic Pivot Table
SET @sql = N'
  SELECT
  [PivotResults].[YM]
 ,[PivotResults].[Zip]
 ,[PivotResults].[Region]
 ,[PivotResults].[NewCallers]
 ,[PivotResults].[RepeatCallers]
 ,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
  FROM
  (
 SELECT
    [CallerTypes].[Name]
   ,[InitialData].[YM]
   ,[InitialData].[Zip]
   ,[InitialData].[Region]
   ,[InitialData].[NewCallers]
   ,[InitialData].[RepeatCallers]
   ,[InitialData].[CallerTypeCount]
 FROM CallerTypes
 
 INNER JOIN [InitialData]
  ON [CallerTypes].[Name] = [InitialData].[CallerType]
  ) AS InnerSelect
  PIVOT (
 SUM([CallerTypeCount])
 FOR [InnerSelect].[Name] IN (' + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', PivotResults.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
  ) AS PivotResults';
  
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Here is a lightly skimmed down version.
I'm trying to convert this:

```
+========+=======+===============+============+===============+=================+=================+
|   YM   |  Zip  |    Region     | NewCallers | RepeatCallers |   CallerType    | CallerTypeCount |
+========+=======+===============+============+===============+=================+=================+
| 201805 | null  | null          |          3 |             0 | Family / Friend |               3 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201805 | null  | null          |          2 |             0 | Other           |               2 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201805 | 72209 | null          |          1 |             0 | Parent          |               1 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201805 | 85008 | Phoenix South |          1 |             0 | Parent          |               1 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201805 | 85008 | Phoenix South |          2 |             0 | Family / Friend |               2 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201805 | 85008 | Phoenix South |          0 |             3 | Other           |               3 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201806 | null  | null          |          9 |             0 | Professional    |               9 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201806 | 85258 | East Maricopa |          2 |             0 | Parent          |               2 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 201806 | 85258 | East Maricopa |          0 |             2 | Other           |               2 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Into this:

```
+========+=======+===============+============+===============+=================+=======+========+==============+
|   YM   |  Zip  |    Region     | NewCallers | RepeatCallers | Family / Friend | Other | Parent | Professional |
+========+=======+===============+============+===============+=================+=======+========+==============+
| 201805 | null  | null          |          5 |             0 |               3 |     2 |      0 |            0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| 201805 | 72209 | null          |          1 |             0 |               0 |     0 |      1 |            0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| 201805 | 85008 | Phoenix South |          3 |             0 |               2 |     0 |      1 |            0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| 201805 | 85008 | Phoenix South |          0 |             3 |               0 |     3 |      0 |            0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| 201806 | null  | null          |          9 |             0 |               0 |     0 |      0 |            9 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| 201806 | 85258 | East Maricopa |          2 |             0 |               0 |     0 |      2 |            0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| 201806 | 85258 | East Maricopa |          0 |             2 |               0 |     2 |      0 |            0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+--------------+
```

---

`[InitialData]` seems to be okay, I'm struggling to pivot it correctly it I think.

I'm having columns with the same YM, Zip, and Region being spread out when they could have been on a single row. The first four rows are an example of that.

It appears to be separating by the Caller Type and not sharing rows with other Caller Types, but the 11th row `(201805, 85008, Phoenix South, 2, 0, null, 2, null, null, 2)` goes against that logic, and also displays `2` in the 4th column when in theory it should be `4` (the sum of all Caller Type counts)

*This is also wrong because this would be the 12th row in the `[ExpectedResults]` where the value is combined further into `9`).*

I only see this happen when all of the Caller Type counts are either `null` or the same value as each other (`2`).

My current idea is that I might need to also pivot on both New and Repeat Callers, but I'm not sure how to do that just yet or if it's a valid answer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you expecting as output? Also fwiw, it is better to include the details in the question in case sqlfiddle site is down.

Comment: The 2nd result set on SQL fiddle, `ExpectedResults`, is what I'm expecting. And yeah, I understand that principal regarding external links, I was worried about having a lot of bloat in the question.

Comment: Can you please post DDL+DML queries to create the table and insert the sample data)? This will give us something to work on directly and test our solution.

Comment: My SQL Fiddle link has that as well

Comment: @RonenAriely In the event that my SQL Fiddle link does not work for you, I've added the scripts to my post and hid them behind the JS Code Snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dynamic query for the static version below

(added on 2018-06-22:49 Israel time)

```
-------------Step 1 ----------------------
-- get the list of [CallerType],
-- which will become our column's names
Declare @ColumnsList1 nvarchar(MAX) = N''
SELECT @ColumnsList1 = 
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([CallerType]) 
        FROM InitialData
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,''
)
-- print @ColumnsList1
-- [Business],[Family / Friend],[Other],[Parent],[Professional]
Declare @ColumnsList2 nvarchar(MAX) = N''
SELECT @ColumnsList2 = 
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT distinct ',
            ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([CallerType]) + ',0) as '+ QUOTENAME([CallerType])
        FROM InitialData
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,''
)
--print @ColumnsList2
/*
            ISNULL([Business],0) as [Business],
            ISNULL([Family / Friend],0) as [Family / Friend],
            ISNULL([Other],0) as [Other],
            ISNULL([Parent],0) as [Parent],
            ISNULL([Professional],0) as [Professional]
*/
Declare @ColumnsList3 nvarchar(MAX) = N''
SELECT @ColumnsList3 = 
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT distinct '+
            ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([CallerType]) + ',0)'
        FROM InitialData
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,''
)
-- print @ColumnsList3
/*
            ISNULL([Business],0)+
            ISNULL([Family / Friend],0)+
            ISNULL([Other],0)+
            ISNULL([Parent],0)+
            ISNULL([Professional],0)
*/
-------------Step 2----------------------
DECLARE @MyDynQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
;with MyCTE as (
    select *
    from
    (
      select 
        [YM], [Zip], [Region], [IsNew] = CASE WHEN [NewCallers]>0 then 1 else 0 END, 
        [CallerType], 
        [CallerTypeCount] 
      from InitialData
    ) x
    pivot(
        SUM([CallerTypeCount])
        for [CallerType] in(
            ' + @ColumnsList1 + '
        )
    )p
)
select 
    [YM], [Zip], [Region],--[IsNew] ,
    [NewCallers] = CASE
        WHEN [IsNew] = 1 then 0 +
            ' + @ColumnsList3 + '
        else 0
    END,
    [RepeatCallers] = CASE
        WHEN [IsNew] = 0 then  0 +
            ' + @ColumnsList3 + '
        else 0
    END,
    ' + @ColumnsList2 + '
from MyCTE
'
-- Print @MyDynQuery
execute(@MyDynQuery)
GO
```

### This is a static version of a query - Once confirmed as fit, we will post the dynamic version above

```
;with MyCTE as (
    select *
    from
    (
      select 
        [YM], [Zip], [Region], [IsNew] = CASE WHEN [NewCallers]>0 then 1 else 0 END, 
        [CallerType], 
        [CallerTypeCount] 
      from InitialData
    ) x
    pivot(
        SUM([CallerTypeCount])
        for [CallerType] in(
            [Family / Friend], [Other], [Parent]
            ,[Professional],[Business]
        )
    )p
)
select 
    [YM], [Zip], [Region],--[IsNew] ,
    [NewCallers] = CASE
        WHEN [IsNew] = 1 then 0 +
            ISNULL([Family / Friend] ,0) + 
            ISNULL([Other]           ,0) + 
            ISNULL([Parent]          ,0) +
            ISNULL([Professional]    ,0) +
            ISNULL([Business]        ,0) 
        else 0
    END,
    [RepeatCallers] = CASE
        WHEN [IsNew] = 0 then  0 +
            ISNULL([Family / Friend] ,0) + 
            ISNULL([Other]           ,0) + 
            ISNULL([Parent]          ,0) +
            ISNULL([Professional]    ,0) +
            ISNULL([Business]        ,0)
        else 0
    END,
            ISNULL([Family / Friend] ,0) [Family / Friend], 
            ISNULL([Other]           ,0) [Other]          , 
            ISNULL([Parent]          ,0) [Parent]         ,
            ISNULL([Professional]    ,0) [Professional]   ,
            ISNULL([Business]        ,0) [Business]       
from MyCTE
GO
```

### Update information above this line 2018-06-29 21:45 Israel time

Good day Ryan,

Now that I have DDL+DML i can provide a solution pretty fast (assuming I understand the request) :-)

Please check if below queries solve your needs. First when we need dynamic query, I write a simple static pivot query. Only once I think that I got the right solution I move to dynamic query, which is the second query bellow

```
;with MyCTE as (
    select *
    from
    (
      select 
        [YM], [Zip], [Region], 
        [NewCallers], [RepeatCallers], [CallerType], 
        [CallerTypeCount] 
      from InitialData
    ) x
    pivot(
        SUM([CallerTypeCount])
        for [CallerType] in(
            [Family / Friend], [Other], [Parent]
            ,[Professional],[Business]
        )
    )p
)
select 
    [YM], [Zip], [Region], 
    SUM(ISNULL([NewCallers]      ,0)), 
    SUM(ISNULL([RepeatCallers]   ,0)),
    SUM(ISNULL([Family / Friend] ,0)), 
    SUM(ISNULL([Other]           ,0)), 
    SUM(ISNULL([Parent]          ,0)),
    SUM(ISNULL([Professional]    ,0)),
    SUM(ISNULL([Business]        ,0))
from MyCTE
group by [YM], [Zip], [Region]
GO
```

And now assuming the above query works well, we can move to the write a dynamic query.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
-- Now let's do it in dynamic pivot
-------------Step 1 ----------------------
-- get the list of [CallerType],
-- which will become our column's names
Declare @ColumnsList1 nvarchar(MAX) = N''
SELECT @ColumnsList1 = 
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([CallerType]) 
        FROM InitialData
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,''
)
Declare @ColumnsList2 nvarchar(MAX) = N''
SELECT @ColumnsList2 = 
replace (@ColumnsList1,'[','
SUM(ISNULL([')
SELECT @ColumnsList2 = REPLACE(@ColumnsList2,'],','],0)),') + N',0))'
-- print @ColumnsList2
-------------Step 2----------------------
-- Back to the suery we replace the column with the parameter @ColumnsList
DECLARE @MyDynQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
';with MyCTE as (
    select *
    from
    (
      select 
        [YM], [Zip], [Region], 
        [NewCallers], [RepeatCallers], [CallerType], 
        [CallerTypeCount] 
      from InitialData
    ) x
    pivot(
        SUM([CallerTypeCount])
        for [CallerType] in(
            ' + @ColumnsList1 + '
        )
    )p
)
select 
    [YM], [Zip], [Region], 
    SUM(ISNULL([NewCallers]      ,0)), 
    SUM(ISNULL([RepeatCallers]   ,0)),
    ' + @ColumnsList2 + '
from MyCTE
group by [YM], [Zip], [Region]
'
-- Print @MyDynQuery
execute(@MyDynQuery)
GO
```

Comment: I noticed that I forgot to display the column's names... I will update the query after the meeting I start in 3 min (the meeting start in 3 not the update)

Comment: I'm testing your static pivot table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56bc6/6 The 1st result set is the expected and the 2nd is your static pivot. Yours is combining the New and Repeat Callers into the same row which is not what I wanted as I can't determine how many of the Caller Types are New or Repeats. If you look at the row with the Zip code `85008` you'll see that there are 7 New Callers and 3 Repeat Callers (total 10), but there are 12 Caller Types being counted (`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 2`), so the count is off too. This is what I've been struggling with in my original script as well.

Comment: It's really awful interface! I cannot go and travel between interfaces in order to look at the result and you cannot upload images here but only simple one-line comment. How don't see how people can have technical discussion here :-(

Comment: In the original data (table InitialData), is a row can have value ither then 0 for both NewCallers and RepeatCallers, or each row is for NewCallers  or for RepeatCallers?

Comment: If the answer is that each row can have only NewCallers or for RepeatCallers, then I think I understood you, else I it is not clear

Comment: I cannot go over it in depth now, I am in middle of online meeting... but I try to follow since it is already 20:30 here in Israel and when the meeting will end I don't know how much time I will have

Comment: Yes, each row should be a count for either NewCallers or RepeatCallers, not both. You're not obligated to help me, I can wait for when you have more time. I appreciate the help regardless! :)

Comment: We are getting to the weekend which mean that if not today it can be delayed few days, and who know if I will remember. I do not come here almost ever. I Usually help at MSDN where I serve as Moderator. Before this week I think the last time I was here was a year ago or so ;-) ... better to try end it

Comment: OK, the issue is clear and I have another query which should solve it, but... How the hell should I post it?!? I dont want to remove the old wrong answer since it will make the entire discussion irrelevant. I can't leave the previous as answer since it is wrong. I cannot post the query in a comment since I can only post a one-line text.... I am stuck with this interface :-(

Comment: I can send it in private message if you want until I will figure out what I will do in the public. Is this fit you?

Comment: You could just edit your post, and put in **bold** at the top that you've updated your post, there is an edit history so others can look back if they want context. This way if your answer is correct I can mark it as such for future viewers. A private message denies those your solution.

Comment: edit a post meaning edit the history! a discussion is something that chronological order and each comment/response come as respond to specific message at specific time. Yes the history will be save without any relation to the comments and in order to make the relation someone need to start calculate time of each comment in order to know on which version of the updated answer it is related to.

Comment: Moreover I still need your response on my new static pivot before I translate it to dynamic pivot... so what next? I will update the answer again and again and again ?!?? do we discuss over the answer itself or in the comments. It make no sense to me how we can have tech discussion like this. then only solution I find is to use external website for the code, same as you did (which mean what not to have the discussion in external place and come with the final answer if needed...

Comment: I would suggest either updating this post or deleting this post and creating a new one with your updated solution.

Comment: I will do like this: I will add bold text line saying "old version" I will write the static solution for your to confirm above it under the bold line "temp static version" and if you confirm then I will add above a new section with the new dynamic version (which I am not sure I will have time today to get your response and write it). I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: believe = "Accept that something is true, without any proof, empirical evidence, or scientific theory"... I do not like to act on the basis of beliefs :-).  Please check and confirm if you want me to post the dynamic version of this query.

Comment: I did check it, it's correct. It matches my `ExpectedResults` table.

Comment: I posted the dynamic version. have a great day and good night ;-)

Comment: By the way, in step 1 i use 3 queries to get the different version of column's list but fr better performance this can be done in one query and some string manipulation functions

Comment: Thank you for help! I really appreciate it.